# Questões de multipla escolha em php e banco de dados

Tags: php

Olá, estou montando um sistema de busca com filtro para buscar questões de múltipla escolha em um site, de acordo com a disciplina, banca, cargo, ano, etc. Para isso cadastrei as questões em uma tabela no banco de dados e as alternativas em outra tabela. Agora eu preciso que a questão e suas alternativas apareçam juntas. Como faço isso? segue o código:

'

```
//////////////////////DISCIPLINAS//////////////////////////////////////////////
$sql_disciplina = "SELECT * FROM tabela_disciplina ORDER BY Disciplina ASC";
$pega_disciplina = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_disciplina);

    ////////////////////////////////////////BANCAS/////////////////////////////////
    $sql_banca="SELECT * FROM tabela_banca ORDER BY Banca ASC";
    $pega_banca = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_banca);

////////////////////////////////////////INSTITUIÇÃO/////////////////////////////////
$sql_instituicao="SELECT * FROM tabela_instituicao ORDER BY Instituicao ASC";
$pega_instituicao = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_instituicao);

////////////////////////////////////////CARGO/////////////////////////////////
$sql_cargo="SELECT * FROM tabela_cargo ORDER BY Cargo ASC";
$pega_cargo = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_cargo);

////////////////////////////////////////ANO////////////////////////////////////
$sql_ano="SELECT * FROM tabela_ano ORDER BY Ano ASC";
$pega_ano = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_ano);

//////////////////////NÍVEL//////////////////////////////////////////////
$sql_nivel = "SELECT * FROM tabela_nivel ORDER BY id_nivel ASC";
$pega_nivel = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_nivel);

////////////////////////////////TRAZ AS QUESTÕES DE ACORDO COM O CRITÉRIO/////
if(!empty($_POST['bt_enviar'])) 
{
$disciplina = (empty($_POST['Disciplina']))? 'null' : $_POST['Disciplina'];
$banca = (empty($_POST['Banca']))? 'null' : $_POST['Banca'];
$instituicao = (empty($_POST['Instituicao']))? 'null' : $_POST['Instituicao'];
$cargo = (empty($_POST['Cargo']))? 'null' : $_POST['Cargo'];
$ano = (empty($_POST['Ano']))? 'null' : $_POST['Ano'];
$nivel = (empty($_POST['Nivel']))? 'null' : $_POST['Nivel'];
$sql_questao="SELECT * FROM tabela_questao WHERE id_disciplina = $disciplina OR id_banca = $banca OR id_ano = $ano OR id_nivel = $nivel OR id_instituicao = $instituicao OR id_cargo = $cargo";
$seleciona_questao = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_questao);
}

////////////////////////////////TRAZ AS ALTERNATIVAS DE ACORDO COM AS QUESTÕES/////

$query = "SELECT Q.Questao, A.Alternativa
FROM Tabela_questao AS Q
LEFT JOIN tabela_resposta AS A
ON Q.id_questao = A.id_questao";

$executar_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($executar_query)) {?>



<p><?php echo $resultado['Alternativa']; ?></p>

<?php
}
mysqli_close($connection);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Busca</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<span></span>
<select name="Disciplina">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione a disciplina</option>
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($pega_disciplina) == 0) {
echo '<option value="">Não foram encontradas disciplinas</option>';
}else{
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($pega_disciplina)){
echo '<option value="'.$linha['id_disciplina'].'">'.utf8_encode($linha['Disciplina']).'</option>';
}
}
?>

</select>
<span></span>
<select name="Banca">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione a banca</option>
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($pega_banca) == 0) {
echo '<option value="">Não foram encontradas bancas</option>';
}else{
while($linhaB = mysqli_fetch_array($pega_banca)){
echo '<option value="'.$linhaB['id_banca'].'">'.utf8_encode($linhaB['Banca']).'</option>';
}
}
?>


</select>
<span></span>
<select name="Instituicao">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione a instituição</option>
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($pega_instituicao) == 0) {
echo '<option value="">Não foram encontradas instituições</option>';
}else{
while($linhaD = mysqli_fetch_array($pega_instituicao)){
echo '<option value="'.$linhaD['id_instituicao'].'">'.utf8_encode($linhaD['Instituicao']).'</option>';
}
}
?>


</select>
<span></span>
<select name="Cargo">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione o cargo</option>
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($pega_cargo) == 0) {
echo '<option value="">Não foram encontrados cargos</option>';
}else{
while($linhaD = mysqli_fetch_array($pega_cargo)){
echo '<option value="'.$linhaD['id_cargo'].'">'.utf8_encode($linhaD['Cargo']).'</option>';
}
}
?>


</select>
<span></span>
<select name="Nivel">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione o nível</option>
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($pega_nivel) == 0) {
echo '<option value="">Não foram encontrados níveis</option>';
}else{
while($linhaC = mysqli_fetch_array($pega_nivel)){
echo '<option value="'.$linhaC['id_nivel'].'">'.utf8_encode($linhaC['Nivel']).'</option>';
}
}
?>


</select>
<span>Ano</span>
<select name="Ano">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selecione o Ano</option><br />
<br />
<?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($pega_ano) == 0) {
echo '<option value="">Não foram encontrados</option>';
}else{
while($linhaB = mysqli_fetch_array($pega_ano)){
echo '<option value="'.$linhaB['id_ano'].'">'.utf8_encode($linhaB['Ano']).'</option>';
}
}
?>

<br /><br /><input type="submit" name="bt_enviar" value="buscar" /><br />
</form>
<hr />

<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['bt_enviar'])) 
{
if(mysqli_num_rows($seleciona_questao) == 0)
{
echo '<h1>Desculpe, mas sua busca, não retornou resultados</h1>';
}
else
{
echo "<ul>";
while($linhaquestao = mysqli_fetch_array($seleciona_questao)){
echo '<li>'.utf8_encode($linhaquestao['Questao']).'</li>';
}
echo "</ul>";
}
}

?>

'
```

Comment: O seu banco de dados é MySQL?

Comment: É sim @EduardoAlmeida

Comment: Pode ser mais especifica quando se refere a questões e suas alternativas?

Comment: CArolina, poderia da uma organizada no código? Fica quase impossivel entender do jeito que está, nem organizei porque não entendi bem sua organização.

Comment: Desculpa, eu tentei colocar como código, colocando ' ' mas eu não consegui

Comment: Oi, Carolina! Desculpa ter-me afastado. Bem, gostaria de saber se conseguiste resolver essa questão. Como está o andamento de tudo?

Comment: oi @EduardoAlmeida, ainda estou na mesma. Usando o left join como vc indicou, aparece na tela todas as alternativas que foram cadastradas na minha tabela de alternativas, isso sem eu ter feito a busca pelas questões. E quando faço a busca continua aparecendo apenas as questões sozinhas e as alternativas todas juntas, que já apareciam antes da busca.

Answer (score 1):

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Você poderá imprimir os valores da seguinte forma, então.

```html
<?php
//sua query: se ficar muito grande passe pra uma variável, só por questão de visualização

$query = "SELECT Questao.Questoes AS questao, Alternativa.Alternativas AS alternativas
FROM TABELA_DE_QUESTOES AS Questao
LEFT JOIN TABELA_DE_ALTERNATIVAS AS Alternativa
ON Questao.ID_Questao = Alternativa.ID_Questao";

$executar_query = mysqli_query($con, $query); //primeiro sua conexao, depois sua query

//iteração pelos resultados
while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($executar_query)){ ?>

<h1><?php echo $resultado['questao']; ?></h1>

<p><?php echo $resultado['alternativa']; ?></p>

<?php
   
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Perceba: eu [escapei o HTML](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) no loop `while()`.

Use sempre as [funções mysqli](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/guia-pratico-de-mysqli-no-php) e não as `mysql`, porque estão obsoletas.

Posta os resultados pra gente ver como tá indo.

------------------------------------*

É bem simples, Carolina. Use o `LEFT JOIN` pra associações 1:N (um registro de uma tabela - questão - pra vários registros de outra tabela - escolhas/alternativas).

Um exemplo do uso seria o seguinte:

```html
SELECT Questao.Questoes, Alternativa.Alternativas
FROM TABELA_DE_QUESTOES AS Questao
LEFT JOIN TABELA_DE_ALTERNATIVAS AS Alternativa
ON Questao.ID_Questao = Alternativa.ID_Questao
```

**Explicando:**

Na primeira linha da [query](http://www.dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/o-que-e-sql/), eu coloquei **Questao.Questoes** e **Alternativa.Alternativas**: a primeira palavra é um apelido que eu dei pra cada tabela usando a palavra `AS` a segunda palavra é o nome do campo.

Na segunda linha, fica explícito onde eu dou o apelido pra tabela de questões e, na terceira linha, eu dou um apelido pra tabela de alternativas e me refiro a ela por meio das palavras-chave `LEFT JOIN`.

Na última linha, eu termino o `LEFT JOIN`, que usa a palavra `ON` pra **agrupar os valores** das duas tabelas por meio de um **campo comum**, no caso do exemplo, o campo é `ID_Questao` que deve existir nas duas tabelas, por isso o sinal de igual (pode ser qualquer sinal de comparação, mass é mais comum procurar por igualdades, uma vez que há outros [tipos de JOIN](http://www.luis.blog.br/join-ou-juncoes-sql-inner-left-right-e-full-outer-join.aspx) pra outros tipos de associações ou junções).

Bem, tenta e manda os resultados pra galera aqui!!!

Comment: humm legal, quando eu coloquei isso no banco de dados deu certo. Mas como e onde eu coloco isso no meu código, para aparecer no site? e como fica o echo? ficou assim: 
'SELECT Q.Descricao, A.Descricao
FROM Tabela_questao AS Q
LEFT JOIN tabela_resposta AS A
ON Q.id_questao = A.id_questao'

Comment: Eu editei a questão com um exemplo de aplicação do código.

Comment: hummm, nesta parte: <h1><?php echo $resultado['questao']; ?></h1>

<p><?php echo $resultado['alternativa']; ?></p>
 a questão e a alternativa seriam os campos da tabela? pq nas minhas tabelas estes dois campos estão com o mesmo nome: Descricao. Não deu certo, deve ser por isso. Vou tentar mudar.

Comment: Sim, são os campos da tabela. Na verdade, se você olhar na query do exemplo, eu dei apelidos aos campos retornados do banco de dados usando a palavra `AS`. Suponha: `SELECT campo_questao FROM tabela_questao` e `echo $resultado['campo_questao']`, eu estou imprimindo o campo que é retornado na query. O que eu fiz foi: `SELECT campo_questao AS questao...` e `echo $resultado['questao']`, chamando o campo pelo apelido que eu dei.

Comment: certo, isso eu entendi.. mas estou fazendo alguma coisa errada, pois imprimi todas as alternativas da minha tabela na tela sem eu ter filtrado as questões no filtro que criei. vou editar o primeiro código que postei para ver como está

Comment: Tirei essa parte: <p><?php echo $resultado['Questao']; ?></p> pq já tinha acima, no meu filtro.